# Backbone js model / controller assigning json data to variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm having some difficulty with backbone js. Currently, I have a rails app that is giving information to backbone via json. It appears that this is all function correctly because when I navigate to the URL, the json data is displayed. I'm having difficulty when I am using the fetch method. Below is my code:

```
jQuery ->
  class Event extends Backbone.Model
    url: '/events/get_last'
    defaults:
      name: 'This isnt from the server'
      date_of: '2012-03-01'
      max_attendees: '300'

  class EventList extends Backbone.Collection
    url: '/events/get_events'
    model: Event

  class EventView extends Backbone.View
    el: $ 'body'
    model: Event
    initialize: (options) -> 
      _.bindAll @
      @event = new Event
      @event.fetch()
      @render()
    render: ->
      $(@el).append "<span>#{@event.get 'name'}"


  class EventRouter extends Backbone.Router
    routes : 
        '' : 'home'
        'dashboard' : 'render_data_view'
        'default' : 'default_view'
    home: -> 
      console.log "home"

    render_data_view: ->
      event_view = new EventView

    default_view: ->
      console.log 'the default view was hit'

    initialize: ->
      Backbone.history.start(pushState: true)

  event_router = new EventRouter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EventView should bind to its model's `"change"` event so that [`fetch`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch) will trigger things automatically:

> **fetch** `model.fetch([options])`
>
> [...] A `"change"` event will be triggered if the server's state differs from the current attributes.

So your view should look more like this:

```
class EventView extends Backbone.View
  el: 'body'
  initialize: (options) ->
    @model = new Event
    @model.on 'change', @render
    @model.fetch() # This will call `render` automatically.
  render: =>
    @$el.append "<span>#{@model.get 'name'}</span>"
```

A few notes:

1. You rarely need to use [`bindAll`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll) with CoffeeScript, use the [fat arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) instead.
2. The `model` property on views should be set per-instance to a single model (hence the `@event` -> `@model` name change). Collections get their `model` property set in the class definition and the `@model` for a collection should be a model class.
3. Binding to the `"change"` event on the model means that your view will be notified (i.e. `@render` will be called) whenever *anyone* changes the model, this event behavior is sort of the whole point of Backbone so you should use it, the per-`fetch` success and error handlers are more for error handling and reporting success to the user.
4. You really should close your `<span>` elements.
5. The view already has [`@$el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-%24el) so you might as well use that instead of `$(@el)`.
6. You can use `el: 'body'` instead of `el: $ 'body'` and leave the jQueryification to Backbone.
7. If you're using an older Backbone then:

   1. You might have to use `bind` instead of `on`.
   2. You might not have `@$el` so `$(@el)` might be needed instead.

Comment: I really appreciate this detailed answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the backbone docs: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch

```
model.fetch({
 success: function(model, response) {...}, 
 error: function(model, response) {...}
});
```

You should set a success and an error method for the fetch method. When you get a success event, then you can call render().